# How can I get the URL used to launch an XBAP?

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

If someone launches my xbap from `http://myserver/folder/application.xbap`, I would like to get the `http://myserver/folder/` part of the url from within the application.

How can I do that?

I have tried:

- `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
- `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`
- `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
- `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
- `System.Windows.Application.Current.StartupUri.AbsolutePath`
- `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]`
- `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory`

They all return either the local location on my machine that the xbap got downloaded to and is running from, or the location of the executing assembly, such as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

How can I access the URL that was used to launch an xbap application from within the application itself?

Comment: As in the URL of IE? C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/ie.exe

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, the Url that was used to launch the application. The first sentence of my question has an example.

Comment: In SilverLight the App object has a Host property. Is that available in XBAP?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, `App` does not have a `Host` property in XBAPs. I found what I was looking for in [Douglas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13708703/302677), thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was [`BrowserInteropHelper.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.browserinterophelper.source.aspx):

> Gets the uniform resource identifier (URI) for the location from which a XAML browser application (XBAP) application was launched.

Comment: Could you please try it out and report back? It's been a while since I used it.

Comment: Thanks, that object is just what I was looking for :)